# Sharepoint Designer Workflow - value reset itself

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have a SharePoint Designer workflow like the following: (just an example)

If **ActionId** equals 1
Email **InfopathForms:Customer Email**

Sometime later, it changes itself to the following:
If **field** equals 1
Email **InfopathForms:**

Where the field ActionId is lost and the Customer Email is lost too. Also in the email body, all the Lookup fields are also lost...

Has anyone had this problem before...?
This has happened like 6-7 times already... If anyone know a solution to fix it please let me know... much appreciated!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

And is there some way to backup the workflow...? So I can easily restore it after it resets itself..?

Answer (score 0):

sharepoint designer is not the most useful tool for developing and deploying workflows. I have not experieced this problem. Somthing simliar when two dev's were attacking the same list with sharepoint designer. could this be your problem?

Comment: Not really... this is not really true for me... but thanks for your answer anyway..:)

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed similar symptoms when variable names change... Is your InfoPath form changing?  Or are the promoted fields changing?  If so, I would expect this behavior.  Simple fix is to update the variables in the workflow step, and then leave the InfoPath form alone.  :D

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. the infoPath form is not changed at all... I have never changed any existing variable name.. but been adding new variables...

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue.

I found that the lookup fieldname in the `xoml` file is diffrent if you re-link (pick) it.

An example: `FieldName="WFOrder_x0020_Type"` after re-link it is `FieldName="WFOrder_x0020_Type0"`

```
<ns0:LookupActivity ListId="{}{8FC10225-9397-4F5A-88B6-FE4C37A44970}" x:Name="ID645" FieldName="**WFOrder_x0020_Type**" LookupFunction="LookupFriendlyString" __Context="{ActivityBind ROOT,Path=__context}" ListItem="{ActivityBind ROOT,Path=__item}">
```

I open the `xoml` file in textpad and edit all the fields by adding the zero into the fieldname. Saved it and my workflow is working again.

Just to clarify, I did modify the `InfoPath` form and published it, where after my workflow lookup fieldnames got messed up.